# Adding to ace-editor wise autocomplete: List user-defined functions and variables (javascript language)

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor

I want to add list of user-defined functions and variables to ace editor's  auto-complete. 
To do it I want to examine all the code user inserted to the document, find defined functions (and their arguments), defined variables and their scope, etc.

**Main question**

Is that data already calculated somewhere in the ace source-code (or language-plugin) and I can just grab it in a way?`

**What I want**

for exapmle, if user inserted code like this:

```
var var0 = 'abcd';

function foo(var1, var2){
  var var3 = 'efg';
}
```

I want to add to the auto-complete box, function called 'foo' with two parameters - var1 and var2. I want to add also var0 to variables list, and to add var3 just when user writes in the scope it's defined (in the function).

**What I already knows** :

- I know how to enable auto-complete and live auto-complete.
- I know how to [add new completer](http://plnkr.co/edit/6MVntVmXYUbjR0DI82Cr?p=preview)
- I know that built-in Basic auto-complete adding all the words in document Indiscriminately
- I know about [ace-tern plugin](https://github.com/sevin7676/Ace.Tern), and I don't think I want to use it. For now it's still hackish, documention-less, and I can't figure how to enable it.
- I know that **Ace already have some of the data I'm after**. For example it warns when a variable is re-defined when already defined in the same scope. So it had list of variables and their scope. My guess it's using jshint - but Is there a way to grab it from there?
- I read [ace documation](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=edit_session) and find a lot useful methods I can use to extract the data, if I have to. The question is if I really need to do this myself.

Comment: Did you read that:
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Creating-or-Extending-an-Edit-Mode#extendingTheHighlighter

I also recommending you to see the issues, and pull request (open/close)

Comment: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/pulls
for example: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/pull/2213

Comment: Yes, I read wiki pages, and search in github issues/PR. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE: I implied that in my answer, but to clarify - Tern will do exactly what you are asking in **what i want**. Snippet below solves one more problem of providing some context which you do not want user even see in the editor. See screenshots of your code used at [Ace.Tern live demo](http://sevin7676.github.io/Ace.Tern/demo.html#javascript)

[image: autocomplete for function with two parameters]
[image: inside function scope you have var0, var1, var2 and local var3]

That is opionated,but imo the best option for adding auto-complete in ace is [Tern](http://ternjs.net/doc/demo/#simple).

Tern accepts typedef configuration option ( described here: http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#typedef), but what is more interesting, it will accept your custom js object as a child, ie:

```
var myContext = {
   name: 'myContext',
   obj: obj
}
```

Where `obj` is your js object. Then in Tern configuration you will use it as:

defs: ['underscore', myContext]

Which will use both your custom object and underscore module for autocomplete.

Tern related ace.js config: (See https://github.com/sevin7676/Ace.Tern/blob/master/demo.html for comments on config options)

```
  var myContext = { ... }

  var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.getSession().setUseWorker(true);

    ace.config.loadModule('ace/ext/tern', function () {
        editor.setOptions({
            enableTern: {
                defs: ['browser', 'ecma5', myContext],
                plugins: {
                    doc_comment: {
                        fullDocs: true
                    }
                },                    
                useWorker: true,                    
                startedCb: function () {
                    console.log('editor.ternServer:', editor.ternServer);
                },
            },
            enableSnippets: true,
            enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks promising.